# WordPress dashboard menu is not shown and the functions have dissapeared?

Tags: wordpress, menu

Suddenly the menu in the WordPress dashboard has disappeared and the functions (themes, plugins, pages... etc) are not being shown.

Here is a screenshot of this issue:

[image: dashboard]

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Seems like your user doesn't have enough permissions to access the rest of the Dashboard. Try logging in with a different account (or, if you don't have another account, [create a new admin account](https://wpengine.com/support/add-admin-user-phpmyadmin/) and log in with that one.)

Comment: Alternatively, try [disabling all of your plugins](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_disable_all_wordpress_plugins_directly_from_database/) and see if that fixes the problem (make a backup of your database first!)

Comment: @cabrerahector whats the username and password for the link you give me above ?? even am sure that am the admin and i didnt create any users !

Alternatively,, i disabled all plugins but the same problem

Comment: You mean the link from the first comment? Check with your hosting provider, they should be able to give you the access credentials if you don't have them.